# How to avoid skipping double quotation when save in Json line?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have file in `jsonl` format as shown below :

`input.jsonl`

```
{"file_name": "input_image.jpg", "text": "II. Firtos. Jelige: \"Vándor daruid V betűje szállt.\""}
```

I am reading this file using pandas :

```
def load_jsonl1():
    return pd.read_json(
                        path_or_buf = 'input.jsonl',
                        lines=True,
                        )
df1= load_jsonl1()
df1.head(1)
```

after showing first row we see there is `\` missing :
`II. Firtos. Jelige: "Vándor daruid V betűje szállt."`
I wrote the following :

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file_name', 'text'])
output_path =  'output.jsonl'
# create output.jsonl file
with open(output_path, 'w') as outfile:
  # to add taqd to see progress
  for idx in tqdm(range(len(df1))):
    image_path = os.path.join(path, df['file_name'][idx])
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    for i in range(sample_amount):
      augmented_image = augment_img(image)
      augmented_image_path = os.path.join(aug_imgs, 'aug_' + str(idx * sample_amount + i) + '.jpg')
      augmented_image.save(augmented_image_path)
      # write updated label to output.jsonl file
      outfile.write('{"file_name": "' + os.path.basename(augmented_image_path) + '", "text": "' + df['text'][idx] + '"}\n')
```

I want to keep all the text with all symbols as it is in `input.jsonl` for the later case needed
so what I am expacting after reading file with `pandas` and save in `ouput.jsonl` file  same as the origin file

`{"file_name": "input_image.jpg", "text": "II. Firtos. Jelige: \"Vándor daruid V betűje szállt.\""}`

Comment: A `\"` in JSON indicates a quote mark. The backslash is there to escape the quote.

Comment: yes, I now but I want to keep it `\"` in the resulting  `output.jsonl` file

Comment: If you write the string as JSON (e.g. `json.dumps`) it will escape quotes in the same way.

Comment: thanks @khelwood This not work for me honestly